# How to refactor Java web application for Amazon Web Service?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just migrated my Spring applications from a VPS provider to Amazon Web Service. So what I did were:

1. Redeploy my app inside EC2,
2. Change the DB connection from localhost:3306 to RDS MariaDB,
3. Implementing S3 for all of the file upload operations
4. And etc.

And I managed to make my app steadily running under AWS now.

Now I need to make some enhancement on my app, then I realized that I couldn't simply replicate those RDS and S3 features in my laptop. So I turned to Eclipse's AWS Toolkit because it provides a nice development and testing experience. But I found out that most of AWS Toolkit tutorial in making a java web app is by using **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** resource. Which my current app is not using.

My question now: Do I have to refactor my app to use Elastic Beanstalk? (this approach surely not in my favor)... or is there anyway (must be) I can develop java web app in AWS without using Elastic Beanstalk and still using the privileges of AWS Toolkit?

Please anybody who has done this before care to show me a link or tutorial?

Regards,
Bromo

Comment: No, you don't need to migrate the app to Elastic Beanstalk (though you probably could if you wanted to). EB is just one of many options for deploying code to AWS. One of the advantages of cloud is that you can easily spin up a parallel environment in which to do testing before you deploy to your production system. How were you deploying production updates when your system ran in the VPS provider?

Comment: Yep... I know that, because I did by using EC2... my question is more on how to use AWS Toolkit to update my app that is not using Elastic Beanstalk....

Comment: There are many options so you should read https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/overview-of-deployment-options-on-aws.pdf to help you decide. From the minimal information available, CodeDeploy might be the simplest and most appropriate option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to, or even need to use Elastic Beanstalk. What you have done so far is perfectly reasonable. Also, Elastic Beanstalk really won't help you with the issue of running things locally. It would help you to spin up a test environment on AWS, but you would still have the same issues if you wanted to run it entirely locally.

Regarding running things from your local laptop, you should be able to run a database server locally. Is there a specific reason you can't seem to get your application to connect to a local database when running on your local computer, instead of trying to connect to an RDS database?

For S3 you could maintain a separate set of code that uses the local file system when running locally, although that would prevent you from testing your S3 code. Alternatively you could setup a "test" S3 bucket and have your code connect to that S3 bucket when running locally. Another alternative would be to run some sort of S3 emulator service locally, like [this](https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3), but I've never used one of those so I can't say how well that would work.

Comment: I still have my original code in which using local db and filesystem. But then I have to maintain 2 version of codes... the reason why I wanna use AWS Toolkit is to skip those Commit to repo, Pull from my EC2, Compile then test my app too many times... just to see whether or not my controller or service is working as expected (disregard the unit test)

Comment: There should not be 2 versions of code to support different database servers. It should just be a matter of changing your database connection string, which should probably be an environment variable.

Comment: Yep correct.. I actually use tomcat jndi or context.xml... I guess its more on s3... maybe I just refactor the S3 related part to enable 1 version of code